# SQLite use it for websites, but not for client/server apps?

Tags: sqlite, web, e-commerce

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630/sqlite-vs-mysql) and the suggested [link explaining when is more appropriate to use SQLite vs another DB](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) it's still unclear to me one simple thing, and I hope someone could clarify it.

They say:

> **Situations Where SQLite Works Well**
>
> **Websites**
>
> SQLite usually will work
>   great as the database engine for low
>   to medium traffic websites...
>
> ...
>
> **Situations Where Another RDBMS May
>   Work Better**
>
> Client/Server
>   Applications...
>
> **If you have many
>   client programs accessing a common
>   database over a network**...

**Isn't a website also a client/server app?**

I mean I don't understand, **a website** is exactly a situation where I have **many client programs (users with their web browsres) concurrently accessing a common DB** via one server application.

Just to keep it simple: at the end of the day, is it possible for instance to use this SQLite for an ecommerce site or an online catalog or a CMS site with about 1000 products/pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite can allow multiple client reads but only single client write. See: https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html

Client/server is when multiple clients do simultaneous writes to the database, such as order entry where there are multiple users simultanously inserting and updating information, or a multi-user blog where there are multiple simultaneous editors.

A website, in the case of read-only, is not client/server but rather simply a server with multiple requests. In many cases, a website is heavily cached and the database is not even accessed, or rarely.

In the case of a slightly used ecommerce website, say a few simultaneous shoppers, this could be supported by SQLite, or by MySQL. Somewhere there is a line where performance is better for a highly-concurrent database as opposed to SQLite.

Note that the number of products/pages is not a great way to determine the requirement for MySQL over SQLite, rather it is the number of concurrent users, and at what point their concurrent behavior experiences slowness due to waiting for locks to clear.

Answer (score 5):

The users' web browsers don't directly access the database; the web application does. And normally the request/response cycle for each page the user views will be very fast, usually lasting a fraction of a second.

IIRC, a transaction in SQLite locks the whole database file, meaning that if a web app request requires a blocking transaction, all traffic will effectively be serialized. This is fine, for a low-to-medium traffic website, because many requests per second can still be handled.

In a client-server database application, however, multiple users may need to keep connections open for longer periods of time, and may also need to perform transactions. This is far less of a problem for bigger RDBMS systems because locking can be performed in a more fine-grained way.

Comment: Thanks! Well I updated the question (I know it's not the browser accessing the DB directlty) but i understood what you are saying. Obviously an online catalog/CMS/ecommerce is going to have a control panel to insert/update/delete items/pages. So what if such control panel could be accessed by 2/3 users concurrently from 3 browsers. I understood SQLite locks the entire DB so is not that efficient, but beside this: can we consider this still NOT a client/server application becasue all control panels are still accessing the same server app and this last one is the only one accessing the DB?

Comment: ...CONTINUED... sorry my last comment was a bit convoluted. You explained it very well when you say: "...multiple users may need to keep connections open for longer periods of time", I would simply like at this point to hear your thoughts on a specific case of a website with an online catalog of not more than 1000 products.

Comment: The amount of traffic will matter more than the number of products in your catalog. If you think your site will have low-to-medium traffic, SQLite may be fine. Ideally, use a database abstraction layer so that you can switch to another database if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

A website isn't necessarily a client server application in the context of use.

I think when they say website, they mean that the web application will directly manage the database. That is, the database file will live within the web site and will not be access via any other means. (A single point of access, put simply)

In contrast, a client/server app may have the web site accessing the data store *as well as*  another web site, SOAP client or even a smart client. IN this context, you have multiple clients access one database (server). This is where the web site would become (yet another) client.

---

Another aspect to consider when constrasting the two, is what is the percentage of writes compared to reads. I think SQLite will perform happiply when there is little writing going on compared to the amount of reads. SQLite, I understand, doesn't do well in a multiple write scenario. It's intended for a single (handful?) process to be manipulating it.

Answer (score -1):

I mainly only use SQLite on embedded applications. (iOS, Android). For larger, more complex websites (like your describing) I would use something like mySQL.

Comment: I don't think an online catalog with max 1000 products/pages is a complex site. I think SQLite can handle that complexity.